# Linq to twitter error

Tags: c#, linq, api, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'd like to retrieve an user's statuses to display them in a listbox (in a webform).
Here is my code :

```
var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext();

var publicTweets =
from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
where tweet.Type == StatusType.User && tweet.ScreenName == txtName.Text
select tweet.Text;

_status = publicTweets.ToList();
```

But it crashes at the last line with the following message :
Input string was not in a correct format.

Why?

How can I do this correctly?

Cordially,

KiTe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your code and it worked.
Try to exactly specify tweet.ScreenName with some constant string:

```
tweet.ScreenName == "username"
```

One more variant to try is `tweet.ID == "username"`.

Comment: I have tried again the same code and it works well. that's weird. Maybe twitter was overloaded.